# pandas: aggregate array during groupby, equivalent of SQL's array_agg?

Tags: pandas

I've got this dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    { 'id': 1, 'spend': 60, 'store': 'Stockport' },
    { 'id': 2, 'spend': 68, 'store': 'Didsbury' },
    { 'id': 3, 'spend': 70, 'store': 'Stockport' },
    { 'id': 4, 'spend': 35, 'store': 'Didsbury' },
    { 'id': 5, 'spend': 16, 'store': 'Didsbury' },
    { 'id': 6, 'spend': 12, 'store': 'Didsbury' },
])
```

I've grouped it by store and got the total spend by store:

```
df.groupby("store").agg({'spend': 'sum'})\
    .reset_index().sort_values("spend", ascending=False)

store        spend   
Didsbury     131  
Stockport    130
```

Is there a way I can get the IDs for each store as a column in the grouped object? Like the equivalent of `ARRAY_AGG` in Postgres? So the desired output would be:

```
store        spend   ids
Didsbury     131     [2,4,5,6]
Stockport    130     [1,3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`named_aggregations`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#enhancements), which is an aggregation method available since `pandas >= 0.25.0`.

Notice how we can instantely rename our column to "ids":

```
df1.groupby('store').agg(
    spend=('spend', 'sum'),
    ids=('id', list)
).reset_index()
```

```
       store  spend           ids
0   Didsbury    131  [2, 4, 5, 6]
1  Stockport    130        [1, 3]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks - didn't know that method had been added.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `list` like aggregation function for `id` column:

```
df = (df1.groupby("store").agg({'spend': 'sum', 'id':list})
         .reset_index() 
         .sort_values("spend", ascending=False))
print (df)
       store  spend            id
0   Didsbury    131  [2, 4, 5, 6]
1  Stockport    130        [1, 3]
```